# wxPython - Set Items in ListCtrl and Get Selected Item

Tags: python, wxpython

I have the following code for creating a ListCtrl called "browser list".

```
self.browserList=wx.ListCtrl(panel, pos=(20,150), size=(250,100), style.wx.LC_REPORT|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
self.browserList.InsertColumn(0, '')
self.browserList.InsertColumn(1, 'Browser: ')
self.browserList.SetColumnWidth(0, 50)
self.browserList.SetColumnWidth(1, 200)
```

I wante to add the following to add these strings as items, but it puts it in the 1st column, whereas I need it in the 2nd column:

```
self.browserList.InsertStringItem(1, 'Google Chrome')
self.browserList.InsertStringItem(2, 'Mozilla Firefox')
```

Also, how can I get the selected item and store it in a variable?

Comment: Are you using wxPython Phoenix or Classic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than that. You insert the item and then you use SetStringItem to insert data into other columns. Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,100),
                                     style=wx.LC_REPORT
                                     |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                                     )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, '', width=50)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Browser', width=200)

        # add some browsers
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(0, "foo")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(0, 1, "Google Chrome")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(1, "bar")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(1, 1, "Mozilla Firefox")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I personally prefer using ObjectListView instead of the ListCtrl. I just think it works better. But you might find my old tips and tricks tutorial useful:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/04/wxpython-wx-listctrl-tips-and-tricks/

And if you decide to switch, then you might find this one helpful as well:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/

Comment: Instead of "foo" and "bar" how could I make these images?

Comment: You need to create an image list and then call the widget's `SetImageList` method. Looking at the docs, you should be able to use that in conjunction with `InsertStringItem` as its last argument is the `ImageIndex`. See the docs for additional details - http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html

Comment: I don't fully understand InsertImageItem/InsertStringItem...whats the difference? I have the following and its not working:     self.ilist=wx.ImageList(40,40)                                                             images=['/Desktop/firefoxlogo.png', '/Desktop/chromelogo.png']                                                       for i in images:                                                                                                                      self.ilist.Add(wx.Bitmap(i))

Comment: I believe InsertImageItem does not allow you to insert a string AND an image.

Comment: I can't get an image to insert correctly on Linux. You may need to ask on the wxPython Google group.